# Using "mediator" as a sink in a listen-block routine

Tags: javascript, chaplinjs

I have a ChaplinJS project built by someone else, and I'm not fully informed about certain details of the framework. Here's a bit which I'm finding tricky to grok:

```
listen: {
  'change model': 'render',
  'home:actionvideo mediator': 'show'
},
```

This block of code is inside of one of the view JS files. I'm familiar with this style of event-handling, my understanding is the first bit ("home:actionvideo") is the name of an event, the second part ("mediator") is an element selector, and the bit after the colon is the name of a function to run in reponse to the event.

But here in Chaplin-world, I'm thinking "mediator" actually refers to the Chaplin-core `Chaplin.mediator` object. Is this correct?

And while I'm at it, does that first line `change model` somehow listen to a `Chaplin.model`? Which `Chaplin.model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this is correct.**

[chaplinjs](/questions/tagged/chaplinjs) is able to listen to the following methods:

```
var MyView = Chaplin.View.extend({

  events: {
    // Listen to $ DOM events
    'click button': 'methodName',
    'change select#myid': 'methodName',
    ...
  },

  listen: {
    // Listen to Chaplin events
    'onAddedToDOM': 'methodName',
    ...

    // Listen to model events
    'change:foo model': 'methodName',
    // Listen to collection events
    'reset collection': 'methodName',
    // Custom mediator events (or Chaplin events, like router:route etc.)
    'pubSubEvent mediator': 'methodName',
    // The value can also be a function.
    'eventName': function() {alert('Hello!')}
  },
```

Use the `mediator` class, to [publish/ or subscribe to direct communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) through controlled channels:

```
this.publishEvent('pubSubEvent', ['Joe', 'Schmoe']);
```

or outside your view:

```
require('chaplin');

Chaplin.mediator.publishEvent('pubSubEvent', ['Joe', 'Schmoe']);
```

You can find the source code for event delegation here: https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/master/src/chaplin/views/view.coffee#L299-308

Comment: fan-friggen-tastic answer, i like that you included a link to the source code which answers the question. i am lazy but you are not, you get points!